# State in another component is not updated with useEffect after initial render, but it is with button onClick

Tags: reactjs

In first file [Create.js](https://github.com/NikolaGolubovic/invoices-app/blob/main/src/components/Create.js) (sorry for no refactoring code)

I have array with useRef() values,
it is updated as excepted:

```js
const [refsArr, setRefsArr] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    setRefsArr([
      { fromAddress },
      { fromCity },
      { fromPC },
      { fromCountry },
      { toCName },
      { toAddress },
      { toCity },
      { toPC },
      { toCountry },
      { desc },
    ]);
  }, []);
```

Also I have items.map() (short version, some props and container missing),
which include CreateItem component,
and also button which create new item for list inside big form (you can see app [here](https://invoices-app-l11zujkaz-nikolagolubovic985.vercel.app/))

```js
 {itemsList.map((item, itemIndex) => {
              return (
    enter code here
                <CreateItem
                  key={item.id}
                  setRefsArr={setRefsArr}
                  refsArr={refsArr}    />
           <button
                onClick={() => {
                   setItemsList([...itemsList, { id: itemsList.length + 1 }]);
                 }}
                 className="btn-create-item"
            >
                 + Add New Item
             </button>
            )
  })}
```

and also there is [CreateItem.js](https://github.com/NikolaGolubovic/invoices-app/blob/main/src/components/CreateItem.js)
with useEffect with intention to update refsArr

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setRefsArr([...refsArr, [{ itemNameRef, qtyRef, priceRef }]]);
}, []);
```

but after intial render (app is loaded first time), useEffect() from CreateItem doesn't update refsArr.
It is updated after click on button. So I am puzzled how to update my refsArr initially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem simply with

```
setRefsArr((prevArr) => [...prevArr, [{ itemNameRef, qtyRef, priceRef }]]);
```

Further explanation:

[useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Answer (score 3):

Your dependency array for the `useEffect` is empty. A `useEffect` fires on three occasions:

- component mounts
- dependency changes
- component unmounts (return value is executed)

In your case, an empty deps array means the `useEffect` will only fire once on component mount (No dependency array will fire every re-render). For example adding deps here will trigger the `useEffect` when the component re-renders:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setRefsArr([...refsArr, [{ itemNameRef, qtyRef, priceRef }]]);
}, [priceRef]);
```

**Note:** A re-render only occurs when component state changes ie params, hooks, and state. `useState` triggers a re-render, `useRef` **does not trigger a re-render**. Once you research these hooks more, you'll realize having a `useState` value contain an array of Refs is non-sensical. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html

However, I see many other issues with your code. You should not suffix a state value with the word 'Ref', this is confusing because it is not a Ref. You should probably be using `useContext` hook here to manage component state instead of passing along a `setState` function. And most importantly having a `useEffect` be responsible for updating component state instead of callback methods on an element like `input onChange` is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: thank you for your time bugbeeb,  
i gave you upvote even i am not sure you are helpful for my problem :)
i use ref naming to variables which contain useRef().  
i am not trying to trigger a re-render with useRef() and because of that my dependecy array is empty,  
i have problems mainly with items which are stored from my localstorage. (maybe i was not clear enough with that in my explanation). 
but i am not sure why refsArr is not update intially via useEffect in itemList but works regularly with events.